# Creation of Labels for Label Spreading in skicit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf, supervised-learning

I am using Label Propagation in skicit-learn for finding labels for the unknown ones

My Input is 'data_list' containing 400 000 sentences in sanskrit language like :

['tatra yad tad mahABAga SaMkara arDa kAyin',
'gam sa bala SrImant duryoDana ariMdama',
'Sigru pattra Bava SAka rucya vAta kaPa apaha']

I gave this 'data_list' as a parameter to method of fit_transform of Tfidf vectorizer and got a sparse matrix 'X'

Link : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform

```
    X = fit_transform(data_list)
```

I then gave this matrix 'X' to TruncatedSVD to obtain a matrix 'X_reduced' which is dimensionally reduced

```
    svd = TruncatedSVD()
    X_reduced = svd.fit_transform(X)
```

Now to use the 'fit' function of Label Spreading I need to give two parameters 1)the above matrix X_reduced and 2) Matrix with labels

Link : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelSpreading.html#sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelSpreading.fit

```
    label_spread = LabelSpreading()
    label_spread.fit(X_reduced,labels) 
    #fit(X, y)
    #where X : array-like, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
    #y : array_like, shape = [n_samples]
```

For creating Labels, I have a list of words (these are the words that occur in above sanskrit sentences) with name 'unique_words' which has labels of '1' or '0' and '-1' for all other words not in the list

The problem I am facing is X_reduced has no. of rows (n_samples) = no. of sanskrit sentences i.e., no. of elements in the above 'data_list'
and I should create a labels matrix of same numbers of rows as X_reduced

So how to create labels matrix to give as a parameter to 'fit' function of Label Spreading in skicit-learn

Comment: n-th sample of `data_list` remains the same n-th sample in `X_reduced`. So, just create labels using original `data_list` and use it as `labels` in `label_spread.fit`.

Comment: As i posted above, i can create labels for words in 'unique_words' meaning i have labels for words '1' for the ones in the list and '-1' for the words not present in the list

Comment: i don't have labels for sentences(samples)

Comment: I believe you make something wrong. Code you've posted will train model to classify the whole sentence. It's supervised learning, so YOU have to know how it had to be classified. Maybe you want to distinguish sentences that contain at least 1 'unique_word' from other sentences? Or you want each class fitted to exact number of 'unique_words' with certain label (0 or 1)? And do you want that 'not labeled samples' correspond to sentences, that have at least 1 word with label '-1'? Or maybe to sentences, where half of words have label '-1'?

Comment: I have labels for only some words in the sentences and all other words have labels '-1'.what i want is i want label spreading algorithm to propagate the labels of labelled (words)data to unlabelled (words)data using sentences as edges(or something).
But as you said it is classifying the whole sentences so what should i do?

Comment: I guess you should post in [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) Stack a question about which methods you should use to solve your problem.

Comment: I thought a bit and can suggest such scenario: 1) extract all words from sentences. If sentence have ≈7 words, you'll have 2.8 M samples. And now you have a label for each sample. 2) Each word you have has to be represented as bunch of features, e.g.: - number of vowels; - number of letters; - presence of capital letter amidst; - position in sentence etc. It will be much easier if you know why certain words have certain labels. 3) Now use `LabelSpreading`. Don't forget to pick out labeled words for cross-validation to ensure that model is valid with chosen features.

Comment: I did the label propagation taking words as samples, i got the labels but tfidf vectorizer took the words as features itself.
In the Labels obtained, the Labelled data(for some of the words) along with unlabelled data are also changed

Comment: It looks like underfitting. Try to add some features. Also you can try to experiment with LabelPropagation parameters: change kernel, alter kernel parameters.

Comment: rbf kernel gave MemoryError as it uses dense matrix and how can i add features as it is taking all the words as features itself

Comment: Look at my comment earlier. Represent a word as [number of vowels, number of letters, presence of capital letter amidst, position in sentence ...] E.g. `'tatra'` will be represented as [2, 5, 0, 1, ...]. Try to figure out what features are essential.

Comment: So i tried this example given in sklearn website http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/semi_supervised/plot_label_propagation_structure.html#example-semi-supervised-plot-label-propagation-structure-py

i modified the labels and assigned labels to some indices and what i found is the algorithm in-fact is changing the Labelled data 'labels' along with unlabelled data what is the reason behind this?
(i am also trying what u suggested)

Comment: It's underfitting. I made a simple example: words, whose labels are number of vowels. I have words 'house' labeled 3 and 'horse' labeled 2. Each word is represented as [number of letters, last letter]. So, both words are represented as (5, 2) and LabelSpreading can't find out why they have different labels. So, it assign to both words the same label, which is more spreaded among samples. Check the code [here](https://kobra.io/#/e/-KJEftv_yVVHhBwohQR4).

Comment: that was a very good example! Thank you! now regarding the problem what i think is splitting the sentences into words and running label spreading on words would defeat the purpose of spreading labels using sentences right?

Comment: I think yes, it will work if there will be enough information in features you'll create.

Comment: I got one idea what if i passed sentences as samples and if i transposed the matrix obtained from tfidf,i will get the labels by comparing features as now features would be no. of rows, will that work?

Comment: Then all your features will contain info only about word frequency. And nothing at all about word structure. It will give you acceptable result If your labels are based on word distribution.

Comment: My labels are NERs and non-NERs, NER meaning Named Entities. My work is based on Named Entity Recognition.Can you tell me relevant features to extract based on these?

Comment: I think I can't give you an answer qualitative enough. Try to ask this question in [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [DataScience](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/) Stack, described your problem as clear as possible.

Comment: Thank you! You did help me a lot!! :)